# Linux RT Preempt - Are POSIX threads required?

Tags: linux, multithreading, c++11, real-time

I've read through [this example](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/realtime/documentation/howto/applications/application_base) and browsed through [this wiki](https://rt.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/HOWTO:_Build_an_RT-application) regarding real-time application development with a PREEMPT patched kernel.  The former uses POSIX threads and the latter only references the need for PTHREAD_PRIO_INHERIT mutexes.

So I haven't seen anything that says I explicitly need POSIX threads to take advantage of the PREEMPT patch, but it seems suggested in a way.  Would I still receive the benefit of the PREEMPT patch if I implemented native C++11 threads or boost threads?

Thanks

Comment: Just to mention, last time i tried using C++11 threads in g++, IIRC i needed to link against libpthread anyway.

Comment: This is true, so I'm inclined to think the C+++11 threads might still be OK, but that's not much more than a hunch.

Answer (score 2):

Late answer, but still...

On Linux (and other Unix systems) C++ std threads are often implemented on top of pthreads. The C++ interface is often much more type safe and convenient, but for some things you need the raw Posix interface. For example, priority inheritance mutexes, and some thread scheduling settings, are not (yet, at least) available with std::threads. I have sometimes cheated and mixed Posix primitives and the std::thread primitives, it has worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

On POSIX systems `std::thread::native_handle()` can be used to gain access to underneath pthread. See example here:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/native_handle